# Why using validators=[URLValidator] when defining a model CharField doesn't make it check for URL-validity upon saving the corresponding ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, forms, url, url-validation

**app.models.py:**

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.db import models

class Snapshot(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1999, validators=[URLValidator])
```

**app.forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Snapshot

class SnapshotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snapshot
        fields = ('url',)
```

**app.views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SnapshotForm

def index(request):
    snapshot_form = SnapshotForm(data={'url': 'not an URL!'})

    if snapshot_form.is_valid():
        snapshot_form.save()

    return HttpResponse("")
```

Why does it save 'not an URL!' into DB, despite the fact that it ain't a valid URL?!

What is the right way to incorporate **URLValidator**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified the validators for your field like so: `validators=[URLValidator]`. This is incorrect because the `validators` argument takes in a list of **callables** that perform the validation. In this case even though `URLValidator` is callable but that's actually the `__init__` method of the class being called. You need to pass an instance of the class for it to work properly:

```py
# Note the brackets after URLValidator to instantiate the class
url = models.CharField(max_length=1999, validators=[URLValidator()])
```

Better yet since you want to take input a URL you should simply use the [`URLField` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) for your field:

```py
url = models.URLField(max_length=1999)
```

Comment: I thought instantiating a Class in Python calls its `__init__` ?!

Comment: How would you specify schemes when using a `URLField`?

Comment: @chakmeshma yes instantiating a class will call `__init__` and that's what I said? The validator classes have a `__call__` method to make the instances callable. You cannot specify the scheme if you use `URLField`.